# Paypal API help to pull all available Option Values from transaction

Tags: php, api, paypal, transactions

I'm working on backfilling a database with a couple of years worth of online registrations, and running into problems.  I know I can set up the PayPal IDT to capture incoming transactions, but I'm trying to work on the historical stuff currently.

I found out that the Download History function in PayPal only displays the first two of the Option Variables that are passed with a transaction.  So I figured I'd take a look and try to stumble through figuring out the API for PHP.

It does the same thing.

If I submit to the PayPal cart:

```
on0: Membership Type
os0: Adult
on1: Attendee Name
os1: John Doe
on2: Badge Name
os2: John
on3: Age
os3: 35
on4: Address
os4: 1111 Main Street
on5: City
os5: Chattanooga
on6: State
os6: TN
on7: ZIP
os7: 37421
```

Everything shows up fine in the verification email, and I can SEE all of the values if I look at the individual Transaction Details.  However Download History only shows the values for os0 & os1.

Likewise the GetTransactionDetails method of the API gives me this:

```
'L_TAXAMT0' => '0.00',
'L_SHIPPINGAMT0' => '0.00',
'L_HANDLINGAMT0' => '0.00',
'L_CURRENCYCODE0' => 'USD',
'L_OPTIONSNAME0' => 'Membership Type',
'L_OPTIONSNAME1' => 'Attendee Name',
'L_OPTIONSVALUE0' => 'Adult',
'L_OPTIONSVALUE1' => 'John Doe',
'L_OPTIONS1NAME0' => 'Attendee Name',
'L_OPTIONS1VALUE0' => 'John Doe',
'L_TAXABLE0' => 'true',
'L_AMT0' => '40.00',
```

Does anyone have any ideas or recommendations on where to pull this data?  I don't care if it's from a CSV, API or whatever...  I can adapt to the information that I get.  But I really need to be able to get to all of the fields, preferably without having to write an automated screen scraper for the PayPal site.  :-)

Thanks!

PS. I swear that I've tried searching, but the PayPal documentation is a bit sparse...  and what's there is honestly pretty confusing for a neophyte programmer.  Not to mention that some things point to the REST API, and others to the Classic API.  /sigh

Answer (score 0):

Not everything is available via the reporting as well as API's out there . You can make use of the IPN and you should be getting the required values in the IPN response . I ran a test in sandbox passing the same info as you did in the above post and I got back those values in IPN data . I have attached the IPN data that I received :

[image]

Below is the raw text :

IPN Text

```
mc_gross=0.01 &protection_eligibility=Eligible &address_status=confirmed &payer_id=ASASSZ
7H3XAA &tax=0.00 &address_street=cxas asa &payment_date=15:36:14 Apr 04, 2015 PDT &
;payment_status=Completed &charset=UTF-8 &address_zip=95616 &first_name=Eshan Personal T
est &option_selection1=Adult &option_selection2=John Doe &option_selection3=John &op
tion_selection4=35 &mc_fee=0.01 &option_selection5=1111 Main Street &address_country_cod
e=US &option_selection6=Chattanooga &address_name=Eshan Personal Test Account &option_se
lection7=TN &notify_version=3.8 &option_selection8=37421 &payer_status=verified &business=XXXXXX &address_country=United States &address_city=FL &quantity=1 &verify_sign
=A-STDlxWN9oTKj5bZgqIQ2dxlUMtAicSaetcq4mG7LdKFUi0SHGpc98G &payer_email=XXXX &
;option_name1=Membership Type &option_name2=Attendee Name &option_name3=Badge Name &opti
on_name4=Age &option_name5=Address &contact_phone=408-767-7151 &option_name6=City &o
ption_name7=State &option_name8=ZIP &txn_id=5MR010070N551094V &payment_type=instant &
;last_name=Account &address_state=FL &receiver_email=XXXXXX &payment_fee=0
.01 &shipping_discount=0.00 &insurance_amount=0.00 &receiver_id=XXXXX &txn_t
ype=web_accept &item_name=Test Item &discount=0.00 &mc_currency=USD &item_number=123
&residence_country=US &test_ipn=1 &shipping_method=Default &handling_amount=0.00 &a
mp;transaction_subject=os0:Adult on1:Attendee Name os1:John Doe on2:Badge Name os2:John on3:Age os3:
35 on4:Address os4:1111 Main Street on5:City os5:Chattanooga on6:State os6:TN on7:ZIP os7:37421 &
;payment_gross=0.01 &shipping=0.00 &ipn_track_id=c46bf582626b6
```

Comment: I'm glad to see that IPN will work to get all of the option variables, but that is for transactions as they come in.  I need to pull two years worth of historical transactions to populate a database, and really don't want to type them in one at a time.  (Talking around 1,500 or so)   That's why I was really hoping to find a way via History export or API calls